# 0%2 coming out to be 1

Tags: c++, c, modulo

I am having a weird problem.
[Here](http://ideone.com/E3mEuE) is the link to the code I am working on with input and output.
The snippet on which I am having problem is posted here

```
printf("before modulo r= %d ,ans =%d\n",r/b,ans );
ans=(ans)%2;
printf("after modulo r = %d ,ans =%d\n",r,ans);
```

One can see that in the second iteration before executing line 24 *ans = 0*,after that it becomes 1 instead of remaining 0 as *0%2=0* . I really cannot understand the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first print doesn't print ans, as your b is a long long int, so r/b is a long long int, which has 64 bits, and your first print will print the first 32 bit as r and the next 32 bit as ans. Your ans is never 0 to begin with.

Please, next time, post your code instead of linking it.

Comment: Further to this - to fix the output, replace `%d` with `%lld`,  or cast `(int)(r/b)` . With `printf`, the argument type (after default promotions) must match the specifier otherwise the behaviour is undefined.